# PyQt4 editable combobox current text

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt4, qcombobox

I'm using an editable QComboBox. What I want to achieve is to be able to type a query into the field and run that query after pressing enter. But not matter how I try to get the typed query, combobox's value is always the first item in the list, not the string I just typed. I tried getting the text by using `self.query_combo.lineEdit().text()` and `self.query_combo.currentText()`, but in no case am I able to get the actual current text value in the field.

Does anyone know why this is so and how to solve it?

```
self.query_combo = QComboBox(query_box)
self.query_combo.setEditable(True)
query_box.layout().addWidget(self.query_combo)
# combo box is filled with some example items
```

The user then proceeds to type in the input text. While typing, the "start query" button is highlighted. Therefore when the user presses the enter key (while the caret is still in the editing field), the widget is going to push that button and start the query. In the query method, the code is as follows:

```
def run_initial_query(self):
    # Query keywords.
    qkw = self.query_combo.currentText()
    # or
    qkw = self.query_combo.lineEdit().text()
```

but neither produces the newly typed value. The combo box always selects the first example list item, that was already in the list. I have a feeling I would have less problems using a QLineEdit, but unfortunately that isn't an option.

Comment: please post some more code, in which way did you try to get the current text?

Comment: Added some code to help illustrate the scenario.

Comment: i assume, the pushButton.pressed() signal is not connected to self.run_initial_query correctly, because you always get the text of the first item. In which way is "start query" button.pressed() signal connected to self.run_initial_query()?

Comment: @DavidNovak. Works fine for me. The problems must all be in the code you haven't shown. This is why you should always post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what you want in this way

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.run_initial_query) 

def run_initial_query(self):
    #Do stuff
    print self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
```

Comment: but this doesnt work if user input text in the ediable QCombobox

Comment: @ChangZhao you can connect multiple signals. Here's the full list: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#signals